# Is there a flex-grow for IE10?

Tags: css, flexbox, flex-grow

Caniuse states partial support with the -ms- prefix http://caniuse.com/#search=flex-grow as far as I can understand

Yet, when testing -ms-flex-grow has no effect in IE10, what am I missing here?

Comment: nevermind, I found -ms-flex:1 to be equivalent of flex-grow:1

Comment: Yes, but that's not all... `-ms-flex: 1;` is shorthand for a few properties: `-ms-flex: 1 1 auto;` (flex-grow | flex-shrink | flex-basis).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[ANSWER UPDATED on November 2017]

flex-grow only supports internet explorer 11+, no -ms- prefix. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow

To find out what works for IE 10, use [Autoprefixer](https://autoprefixer.github.io/)

**1 - Set filter to "ie 10"**

**2 - Type in CSS, for example:**

```
.example {
  flex-grow: 3;
}
```

**3 - Autoprefixer result:**

```
.example {
  -ms-flex-positive: 3;
  flex-grow: 3;
}
```

Now you know what prefix to use for IE 10

Comment: How is this the right answer? That syntax simply means flex-grow:1 and basis: auto!

Comment: @sgrumo updated the answer to reflect my knowledge in 2017

Answer (score 14):

The IE10 equivalent of `flex-grow` is `-ms-flex-positive`

For example,

```
-ms-flex-positive: 1;
```

Comment: @Brett – I’m not sure how to respond.. this is what it is. I would suggest you’re running into either a problem with your implementation or you are coming up against an IE flex bug. Philip Walton has done a wonderful job of cataloguing [IE flex bugs and workarounds](https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs).